# Simplify infinitely recursive function $f(a,b) = a+b\sin( a + b\sin( \cdots ( a + b\sin(a) ) \cdots ) )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, recursion, trigonometric-series

Is there a mathematical method to simplify this infinitely recursive function?

I have tried to approximate it, but for work with the ranges I am considering, precision becomes an important factor.

**the recursion is as follows**

$f_i = a + b \ \sin( f_{i-1} )$       with $f_0 = a$

**For example, 3 stage recursion:**

$a + b \ \sin( a + b \ \sin( a + b \ \sin( a ) ) )$

**Variable ranges if it helps for an approximation**

$a \in [-2\pi , 2\pi]$ and $b \in [0,1]$

P.s. I apologize for the poor formatting. This is my first time in StackExchange.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thank you. I'll go through it and edit my post.

Comment: Recursion $f_i = a + b \ \sin( f_{i-1} )$ is of the general form $f_i=\varphi(f_{i-1})$ with $\phi$ continuous (and even differentiable). Assuming convergence to a finite limit $x$, this $x$ will satisfy equation $x=\varphi(x) \iff x=a+b \sin x$ which has no simple expression (intersection of a line with equation $y=(x-a)/b$ and sine curve).

Comment: I believe the series converges to $c$, where $c$ is related to $a$ with the equation: $c - b \sin(c) = a$. I only realized this with experimentation.

Comment: Let $F(x) = a + b \sin(x)$. Since $|F'(x)| = |b\cos x| \le |b|$ independent of $x$, the map is a contraction when $|b| < 1$ and your sequence $f_{i+1} = F(f_{i})$ will converge to the unique fixed point for $F(x) = x$. ( Not 100% sure about the case $b = 1$ but I believe your sequence also converge to a unique fixed point). You problem reduces to finding the fixed point of $F(x)$.

Comment: I think I understand. Just to clarify, I am trying to solve "Kepler's Equation" for elliptical orbits $E-e\sin(E)=M$.  Through experimentation I found that $E=M+e\sin(M+e\sin(  \cdots M+e\sin(M) \cdot ))$. The series with just 3 or 4 recursions provides a good approximation of $E$ with good precision for $e\leq 0.5$. But for cases with $e$ close to $0.9$, a large number of recursions are required. Thank you again.

Comment: Indeed, "fixed point" iteration methods $f_i=\varphi(f_{i-1})$ are known to have slow convergence in general. You should turn to more efficient ones like Newton-Raphson. it's important not to re-invent the wheel : many people have been working on efficient ways of solving Kepler's equation. See for example http://jgiesen.de/kepler/kepler.html

Comment: Yes, I understand. Well, I was trying to come up with a good method to approximate $E$ without iterations for use in a semi-analytical method. I even tried hard-coding 2 iterations of Newton-Raphson as an equation with $E_0 = M + e \sin(M)$. But since the equations became fairly complex (without the iterations), I wanted to see if I can simplify in other ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my comment ; I discovered it by chance. Think to prefix any comment by @pseudo.

Comment: @jeanmarie Ohh of course. Sorry I'm still getting used to math stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to solve for $E$ Kepler's equation
$$E-e\sin(E)=M$$ there should not be any problem using high-order iterative methods. The only problem is to have a reasonable starting guess.

The solution being bounded $M < E <M+e$, expand as a series around $E=M$ and use series reversion to get
$$E_0=M+\frac{e \sin (M)}{1-e \cos (M)}-\frac{e^3 \sin ^3(M)}{2 (1-e \cos (M))^3 }+\cdots$$ Now, to find the zero of function
$$f(E)=E-e\sin(E)-M$$ use Newton, Halley or Householder method with this guess $E_0$.

In fact; if I properly remember, there are explicit solutions in terms of Lambert hyperfunction writing the equation in the exponential form
$$E \exp\Bigg[\log \left(1-e\frac{ \sin (E)}{E}\right)\Bigg]=M$$

Comment: Thank you. But as I stated in the comments, I was looking for an analytical approximation without iterations. I was aware of Lagrange and Bassel series solutions but requires a lot of trig evaluations. But generally yes, I use a Newton-Raphson with a guess solution for any numerical simulations. (Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation other than to comment at the moment)